# which.max(sapply, train_gibbs, logLik) error

Tags: r, cross-validation, topic-modeling, topicmodels

So, I am following Grun and Hornik (http://www.jstatsoft.org/v40/i13/) method of 10 fold cross validation by calculating perplexity from 10-fold training and test set. But I have error when I create test_gibbs which is stated the end of the code below. Can anybody suggest how to fix this problem? Thanks in advance.

```
R> dim(dtm)
[1]  546 1484
R> fold <- 1
R> range(col_sums(dtm))
[1]   1 192
R> set.seed(0908)
R> folding <-
+  sample(rep(seq_len(10),
+  ceiling(nrow(dtm)))[seq_len(nrow(dtm))])
R> testing <- which(folding == fold)
R> training <- which(folding != fold)
R> topics <- 10 * c(1:5, 10, 20)
R> train <- LDA(dtm[training,], k = k,
+  control = list(verbose = 100))
final e step document 491
R> test <- LDA(dtm[testing,], model = train,
+  control = list(estimate.beta = FALSE))
R> train_gibbs <- LDA(dtm[training,], k = k, method = "Gibbs",
+  control = list(burnin = 1000, thin = 100,
+  iter = 1000, best = FALSE))
R> # this is where the error occurs################
R> test_gibbs <- LDA(dtm[testing,],
+  model = train_gibbs[[which.max(sapply, train_gibbs, logLik)]],
+  control = list(estimate.beta = FALSE, burnin = 1000,
+  thin = 100, iter = 1000, best = FALSE))
```

Error in which.max(sapply, train_gibbs, logLik) : unused arguments (train_gibbs, logLik)

Comment: `which.max` has got only one argument. What is `which.max(sapply, train_gibbs, logLik)` supposed to achieve?

Comment: My understanding of the major purpose of which.max(sapply, train_gibbs, logLik) is to retrieve the index where log likelihood from train_gibbs maximizes. If you see "test" variable created based on VEM methods, model is simply "train" since VEM (my understanding could be wrong) has the value where expectation maximizes. On the other hand, with gibbs sampling, you need to pick the max of log likelihood. I could be wrong, please let me know if I understand wrong...

Comment: Well, it's wrong syntax. You need to correct it.